# How to use TPU in TensorFlow custom training loop?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tpu

I don't use Keras. And I want to use TPUs on Google Colab. Questions:

1. Can `tf.session` automatically use TPUs?
2. What do `tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy`, `tf.contrib.tpu.rewrite`, `tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver` do in TPU computing? Are they all necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Which Tensorflow version are you running? Currently the firmware for TPUs on Google Colab only support 1.14 (I may be wrong with the exact version, but it's definitely 1.x), however if you are using TF2.0, there is TPU support for nightly-2.x on GCP, so perhaps you can give that a try!

Note that in 2.0, you would want to get rid of any "sessions" because that is no longer a thing. Check out the TPUStrategy docs here for more information: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#tpustrategy

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I am working on TF 1.13.1 but I ask this question for "general case".